# Perl/lighttpd regex

Tags: regex, perl, lighttpd

I'm using regex in lighttpd to rewrite URLs, but I can't write an expression that does what I want (which I thought was pretty basic, apparently not, I'm probably missing something).

Say I have this URL: `/page/variable_to_pass/` OR `/page/variable_to_pass/`

I want to rewrite the URL to this: `/page.php?var=variable_to_pass`

I've already got rules like `^/login/(.*?)$` to handle specific pages, but I wanted to make one that can match any page without needing one expression per page.

I tried this: `^/([^.?]*)` but it matches the whole `/page/variable_to_pass/` instead of just `page`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This regexp should do what you need

```
/([^\/]+)/(.+)
```

First match would be page name, and the second - variable value

Comment: Thanks, that matches both even with a trailing / on the end. Is it possible to match variables after that? If I have `/page/var1/var2/`, how would I match all 3 of those?

Comment: I think you can modify it to `/([^\/]+)(?:/([^\/]+))*` so it will match all variables

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/([^.?])+/([^.?])+/
```

That should give you two matches.